# concatenate CSV output

Tags: python, csv

So I am storing the output of my code in CSV file. It works except for one thing. The output of the code is joined, but it is not being stored in CSV as joined. For example, in the console, the result is 3PQO288APBE174443, but is CSV it is
3
PQO
288
APBE
174443

```
import random
import string
import asyncio
import unittest
import csv


async def get_random_string(length):
    # choose from all lowercase letter
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    return (str(result_str))


async def my_function1():
    return (str(random.randint(0, 9)))


async def my_function2():
    return (str(random.randint(100, 999)))


async def my_function3():
    return (str(random.randint(100000, 999999)))


with open('VIN.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['VIN']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    thewriter.writeheader()
    for _ in range(100):
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            VIN = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(my_function1(), get_random_string(3),
             my_function2(), get_random_string(4), my_function3()))

        print("".join(VIN))

        for VIN in VIN:
            thewriter.writerow({"VIN":VIN})

test_str = VIN

res = False
for ele in test_str:

    if ele.isupper():
        res = True
        break

# printing result
print("Does String contain uppercase character : " + str(res))

test_str = VIN

len_VIN = 17

res = True
for ele in range(len(test_str)):

    if len(test_str) == len_VIN:
        res = False
        break
print("VIN length = 17 : " + str(res))
```

I tried shifting the location of a few lines of the code

Comment: You are using join() to print it but __repr__() to write it to the file.  Put your data in a dataclass and add a __repr__() that does what you want or use join when you write it to the file.

Comment: You can use Markdown tables [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support] to better illustrate your issue.

Comment: BTW:  This question is not really what SE is about.  As a new user you would not know that.  This is not a bugfix platform.  If your question was "Is this the best way to contatenate CSV data using the Python CSV module" it would be more appropriate.